# DatePicker Value saved as wrong date in SQLite Xamarin.Forms

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms

Model Code:

```
public DateTime date { get; set; }
```

ViewModel Code:

```
public DateTime date
{
    get => Model.date;
    set
    {
        Model.date = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("date");
    }
}
```

XAML code:

```
 <DatePicker Date="{Binding date}" Format=" MMM d, yyyy"  />
```

SQL insert Code:

```
public void InsertDevotion(Object obj)
{
    sqliteconnection.Insert(obj);
}
```

when saving a DateTime object the Date is one day late.
ex. July 12,2018 in datepicker 
then after executing insertToDb method the date would appear as July 11, 2018 in the list. anyone?

Comment: Where is the code where you save this to the database?

Comment: im using SQLiteConnection. i already updated my question. please check again.

Answer (score 0):

In your property,

```
public DateTime date
{
    get => Model.date.ToLocalTime();
    set
    {
        Model.date = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("date");
    }
}
```

The problem you are facing is because of TimeZones, and how SQLite saves a Date Object. If you convert to local time after loading from DB you shouldn't have any issue.